# reactnative how to control loading of useQuery?

Tags: react-native, hook, loading

I'm working on React-Native. And I have a useQuery hook. I didn't change any code and ran several times, sometimes it works and sometimes not. I don't know why...

```
const PHOTO_RECOMMEND = gql`
  query getAdjacents{
    getAdjacents
  }
`;

//return type : [Int!]

const { data : {getAdjacents : photoList}, loading} = useQuery(PHOTO_RECOMMEND)

//expected result : [1,2,3,6,8, ...]
```

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useQuery.data.getAdjacents')

This error is located at:
```

This Query includes machine learning algorithm, so it costed more time than other Query.
I guess I should make the component wait until the query completed. Is there a good way to do this? Or are there other problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not chaching your data on Apollo your `data` object will be undefined until the request is over. In order to prevent this error you could either use the optional chaining operator, e.g. `data?.getAdjacents`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining or conditionally render your content based on the loading state

Comment: Thanks!! I've solved this thanks to you. I edited my code as this                                             
 ```const { data : recommendData} = useQuery(PHOTO_RECOMMEND)
  const photoList = recommendData?.getAdjacents```